# How to read lines of a text file with specific word to an array and get the first four characters of the last line in that array?

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to read the lines of a txt file with a specific word "Release" to an array and get the first four characters of the last line in the array. Below is the code which I have used. My inputs will be textfilepath. Entries in the text file are as below.

```
1234 Debug  Build1Rel Build2Dbg
1234 Release  Build1Dbg Build2Dbg
1235 Release  Build1Rel Build2Dbg
1235 Debug Build1Dbg Build2Dbg
1236 Release  Build1Rel Build2Dbg
1236 Debug Build1Dbg Build2Dbg
```

Output I need is the first four characters (1236) in last line of Release. Thanks all for your prompt support. But now I need the same code in powershell.

Comment: `String.Substring(0,4)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code helped me to read the first four characters and the characters after third tab of last line and write the details to a XML file.

```
 #Required parameters to set
 param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ControlFilePath,
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MatchPattern,
        [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$OutControlFile
     ) 

    If (Test-path $OutControlFile) {
            Remove-Item $OutControlFile
  }

$LastLine= get-content $ControlFilePath -ReadCount 1000 |  foreach { $_ -match "$MatchPattern" } | Select-Object -Last 1
$BuildNumberDigit=$LastLine.Substring(0,4)
$BuildNumberFormat=($LastLine -split "`t")[2].substring(0)

# Create The Document
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($OutControlFile,$Null)

# Set The Formatting
$xmlWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
$xmlWriter.Indentation = 1
$XmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"

# Write the XML Decleration
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()

# Write the Document
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("BuildVersions")
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("property")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("name","BuildNumber")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("value","$BuildNumberDigit ")
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # Closing Property
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("property")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("name","BuildNumberFormat")
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("value","$BuildNumberFormat")
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # Closing Property
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # Closing BuildVersions

# End the XML Document
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument() #Closing Documents

# Finish The Document
$xmlWriter.Finalize
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

ControlFilepath ==> Path to the txt file where the code in question exists\FileName

MatchPattern ==> Pattern to search for in the txt file

OutControlFile ==> Path to the XML file\Filename

So the output XML file looks like

```
<BuildVersions>
    <property name="BuildNumberDigit" value="1236 " />
    <property name="BuildNumberFormat" value="Build1Rel" />
</BuildVersions>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks rather easy to me, like this:

```
var result = File
  .ReadLines(TextFilePath)
  .Where(c => c.Contains("Release"))
  .Last()
  .Substring(0,4);
```

Comment: Sorry Mosca... I have the modified text file now and using powershell 4.0. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Something with Linq could be fun:

```
var output =  File
    .ReadLines("TextFilePath")
    .Select(l => l.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Where(a => a.Length > 2)
    .Where(a => a[1] == "Release")
    .Select(a => a.Last().Take(4));
```

Assuming you want the first four chars of last segment of the *line*

Answer (score -1):

No need to read the entire file *if* we only need the first occurence:

```
const string fileName = "input.txt", searchWord = "Release";
const int charsAtEnd = 4;
var result = string.Empty; //Holds the result

using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName)) {
    //This is where we'll keep the lines we read
    string line;

    //Keep reading lines until ReadLine() returns null
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        //Check if the line contains the word we need
        if (line.Contains(searchWord) && line.Length > charsAtEnd) {
            //Set the result to the last chars of the line
            result = line.Substring(line.Length - charsAtEnd);

            //Exit the loop early if needed
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all that clutter when you can do it with 1 line of code? Check my answer.

Comment: @MatteoMosca Because the code I posted only reads as much as required, until the string is found, rather than the entire file, which is more efficient. Besides, your answer could use some improvement too: you can pass the predicate to Last(), so the call to Where() is redundant. `var result = File.ReadLines(fileName).Last(x => x.Contains("Release")).Substring(0, 4);`

Comment: The user explained he needs the last line with the "Release" string so I don't see your point about reading just as much as it is needed. The improvement about embedding the filter in the Last() method is correct and more concise, I avoided that just because the OP seemed a bit new to c# and Linq and the Where -> Last syntax might result more clear to understand.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:** Read All lines into string array using `File.ReadAllLines()` method.
**Step 2:** Reverse the Array as you want the string from the end of the string.
**Step 3:** search for word "Release" using `Contains()` method
**Step 4:** if the string "Release" is found then get the first 4 characters from the complete string by using `Substring()` method

Try This:

```
   static string  ReadData()
    {
        string [] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\InputFile.txt");
        Array.Reverse(lines);
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            if(line.Contains("Release"))
            {
                return line.Substring(0, 4);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Why all that clutter when you can do it with 1 line of code? Check my answer.